# Perl regex to convert environment variable format from unix ${foo} to dos %foo%

Tags: regex, environment-variables

I am looking for regular expression to convert environment variables from unix to dos format in a file.
i.e. replace all occurrences of ${SOMEVAR} to %SOMEVAR%

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following regex that will capture literal `$`, the literal `{`, then any number of characters other than `}`, and a literal `}` at the end:

```
\$\{([^\}]+)\}
```

And replace with

```
%$1%
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/QJtBg5NCF8OZeJ7A)

Comment: dont you think it would be enough just to capture `\w` rather than making it so complicated?

Comment: @karthikmanchala: Complicated? :) It is normal to capture non-brackets inside brackets. It is a basic regex. I do not think it is OK to re-post others' regexes, BTW.

Comment: i meant.. complicated wrt logic and not regex.. and about re-posting others' regexes your thinking is correct, BTW. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

Find: `\$\{(\w+)\}`
Replace: `%$1%`